# Open android app on another phone via bluetooth?

Tags: factory-reset, bluetooth, 7.0-nougat, lg

I am trying to get past FRP on an LG M430 (Stylo 3, I am also the owner of it), and the only method that would work seems to require a bluetooth headset to open Google via its mic. Trying to get back into chrome via talkback doesn't work once the phone is restarted, so I'm asking if there's a way to have a second android phone act as a headset to open Google on the LG one.